# Using sibling combinator to change sibling class on SVG using Material-UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, material-ui

I'm trying to animate an SVG picture I created. I also created some transparent rectangles behind the elements I'm trying to animate on mouse hover. The hover is working fine in these elements, i.e., the cursor changes to `pointer`.

Then, I'm trying to animate the other elements above this rectangle on mouse hover, I'm trying to achieve it using the css sibling combinator `~`, but it won't animate the element:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  btcContainer: {
    fill: "none",
    pointerEvents: "all",
    "&:hover": {
      cursor: "pointer",
      "& ~ $btc": {
        transform: "translateY(-20px)"
      }
    }
  },
  caseContainer: {
    fill: "none",
    pointerEvents: "all",
    "&:hover": {
      cursor: "pointer",
      "& ~ $case": {
        transform: "translateY(-20px)"
      }
    }
  },
  coffeeContainer: {
    fill: "none",
    pointerEvents: "all",
    "&:hover": {
      cursor: "pointer",
      "& ~ $coffee": {
        transform: "translateY(-20px)"
      }
    }
  },
  glassesContainer: {
    fill: "none",
    pointerEvents: "all",
    "&:hover": {
      cursor: "pointer",
      "& ~ $glasses": {
        transform: "translateY(-20px)"
      }
    }
  },
  pcContainer: {
    fill: "none",
    pointerEvents: "all",
    "&:hover": {
      cursor: "pointer",
      "& ~ $pc": {
        transform: "translateY(-20px)"
      }
    }
  },
  glasses: {}
});
```

These are my styles using `material-ui`. So, in this example, when I hover over the `glassesContainer` I want the `glasses` class to `translateY(-20px)`.

My JSX for these classes are:

```html
<g>
  <ellipse
    cx="{93.42}"
    cy="{333.54}"
    rx="{10.61}"
    ry="{29.2}"
    transform="rotate(-87.7 94.261 333.8)"
    fill="#020230"
    opacity="{0.6}"
  />
  <path
    data-name="Glasses"
    d="M143.47 293.85a2.25 2.25 0 00-.23-1.21l-15.59-31a6 6 0 00-11.29 2.05l-.42 3.86a2.29 2.29 0 004.55.5l.42-3.87a1.41 1.41 0 012.65-.48l13.7 27.2-21.76-2.36a8.7 8.7 0 00-9.57 7.7l-.05.49a6.72 6.72 0 00-3.93-.43v-.48a8.69 8.69 0 00-7.7-9.57l-21.76-2.36 19.21-23.64a1.39 1.39 0 011.62-.41 1.4 1.4 0 01.86 1.45l-.41 3.87a2.28 2.28 0 104.54.49l.42-3.86a6 6 0 00-3.69-6.19 5.93 5.93 0 00-6.89 1.77l-21.86 26.9a2.21 2.21 0 00-.5 1.2l-1.42 13.12c-.54 5 1 8.86 4.63 11.56 2.82 2.1 6.82 3.4 12.23 4h.19c5.41.58 9.59.17 12.79-1.28 4.11-1.86 6.47-5.33 7-10.3l.07-.7a2.12 2.12 0 013.93.43l-.07.69c-.54 5 1 8.87 4.64 11.56 2.81 2.1 6.81 3.41 12.22 4h.19c5.41.59 9.59.17 12.79-1.27 4.11-1.87 6.47-5.33 7-10.3l1.42-13.13v-.06zm-46.75 8.28c-.45 4.19-2.54 8.84-14.76 7.52h-.19c-12.22-1.32-13.26-6.31-12.81-10.51l1.18-10.85 23.67 2.57a4.1 4.1 0 013.64 4.52l-.73 6.77zm40.78 4.41c-.45 4.2-2.54 8.85-14.76 7.53h-.19c-12.22-1.33-13.26-6.32-12.81-10.51l.74-6.77a4.11 4.11 0 014.52-3.64l23.68 2.57-1.18 10.84z"
    fill="url(#prefix__u)"
    className={classes.glasses}
  />
  <rect
    id="ed5c1aba-a022-4fb4-b81d-ab6d91227823"
    data-name="glassesContainer"
    x="39.51"
    y="249.2"
    width="106.21"
    height="113.13"
    className={classes.glassesContainer}
  />
</g>
```

I'm not sure why it's not working. I also tried removing the `~`, but it didn't work.

The codesandbox for this problem is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-jennings-3idbx?file=/src/App.js

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flip the order of your Glasses path and your glassesContainer rect.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator (emphasis mine):

> The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches the second element **only if it follows the first element** (though not necessarily immediately), and both are children of the same parent element.

So in order for `"& ~ $glasses"` to match your Glasses path, it needs to follow the glassesContainer rect sibling (represented by `&` in this style rule) in the html.

Here's a version of your sandbox that is working for glasses: https://codesandbox.io/s/jss-sibling-combinator-rn2c2.